# Windows Forms - how to set the margin between a stack of controls

Tags: c#, winforms, styling

My question is about a certain problem that I have at the moment but I met it in a lot of situations with different Windows Forms controls. I'm having 17 `labels` like :

```
label 1
label 2
label 3
.
.
label 17
```

And I want to make the space between them bigger, but at the same time to be the same between all the labels. I try to change the `margin` property but it seems to have no impact. So is there a way to set some properties for a stack of controls like in this case?

Comment: Ctrl + Select all controls and use increase vertical spacing functionality of Visual Studio.

Comment: You can use the Margins property, but then you have to place all Labels inside a FlowLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all controls and then go to "Format -> Vertical spacing -> Increase"